# Finding automorphisms of fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, automorphism-group

I have the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$ and i want to find its automorphisms 
that leave $\mathbb{Q}$ invariant, so my attempt is:
I find its minimal polynomial which is $$P(x)=x^4-3$$
Then i know that its automorphisms must send $\sqrt[4]{3}$ to every possible root
of $P(x)$
The roots are $\pm \sqrt[4]{3}, \pm \sqrt[4]{3} i$
and the possible maps are the identity $id$,
$$s_1 : \sqrt[4]{3} \mapsto - \sqrt[4]{3}$$
$$s_2 : \sqrt[4]{3} \mapsto \sqrt[4]{3} i$$
$$s_3 : \sqrt[4]{3} \mapsto - \sqrt[4]{3} i$$
But $ \pm \sqrt[4]{3} i$ are not elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$
So the only automorphisms are $id$ and $s_1$.
Am i right to exclude $s_2$ and $s_3$?
Generally in such problems, should i keep the maps that map only to elements of the field?

Comment: Automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$ must send $\sqrt[4]{3}$ to an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$. In particular, a real number. And yes, at the same time a root of $x^4-3$.

Comment: How do i find those elements, aren't  those the roots of the minimal polynomial?

Comment: Yes, $\pm\sqrt[4]{3}$ only.

Answer (score 1):

Automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$ are maps $f:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})\to\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$ so yes, as @deyore said $f(\sqrt[4]{3})\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})\subset \mathbb{R} $